# how and when to use ～たく思います

Tags: grammar

I see this one in N3 JLPT sample paper

```
ぜひ輸出を検討したく思いますので、
最新のバッグのカタログと価格表を今月中に送っていただけないでしょうか
```

Usually I would say 検討したいと思います, but why would this one use 検討したく思います?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually we Japanese native speaker say 「検討したいと思います」.

「検討したく思います」has the same meaning, but I personally feel 「ぜひ・・・検討したく思います in this example context」 a little bit old-fashioned and unatural, because 「検討したく」＝a condescending expression of「ぜひ・・・検討したい」. If you would like to show your condescending attitute, just「検討したいと思います」 is enough.

Answer (score 3):

「～～したく思います」 sounds more literary, more formal, and probably politer than 「～～したいと思います」. 「～～したく...」 is more used in the written style. For example:

> - お礼を申し上げ**たいと**思い、ご連絡させていただきました。
>     ⇒ お礼を申し上げ**たく**思い、ご連絡させていただきました。(more formal)
> - お話をお聞かせいただき**たいと**思います。
>     ⇒ お話をお聞かせいただき**たく**思います。/ 存じます。(more formal)